# how to fix org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException?

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

I encounter this exception when I'm adding a servlet and servlet-mapping fields on my web.xml then deploy the project using jboss.

How should I fix this?

Here is the full stacktrace

```
11:46:15,723 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Servlet.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Servlet.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "Servlet.war"    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]   at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]

Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011093: Could not load component class Hello   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:113)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:54)    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]   ... 5 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hello from [Module "deployment.Servlet.war:main" from Service Module Loader]   at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:111)   ... 7 more

11:46:15,733 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "Servlet.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Servlet.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Servlet.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"Servlet.war\""}} 11:46:15,734 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:    service jboss.deployment.unit."Servlet.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Servlet.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "Servlet.war"

11:46:15,737 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2"
=> {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Servlet.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Servlet.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"Servlet.war\""}}}} 11:46:15,741 INFO [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Servlet.war in 5ms
```

Here is my project directory structure

[image: Project directory structure]

Here is my web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Servlet</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyFirstServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Hello</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyFirstServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>test.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Check that `Hello` class is in the classpath.

Comment: I use the fully qualified name of the class on my web.xml and it is now working properly. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add below dependency to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-modules</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

If your not using maven download this `jboss-modules.jar` jar and add to your build path

Comment: Nothing's changed. Are there other solution for this?